# in vba, how to create a notepad with character length based on character position

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with the following columns.
Example:

```
      1st Col | 2nd Col | 3rd Col | .... | nth Col  | n+1 col  | n+2 col
1)    ABC     | DEFG    | HIJKLM  | .... | NOPQ     | FJKAM    | MMESVS     
2)    RSTUV   | WX      | YZAB    | .... | WGFWGW   | OISNDDA  | KMAM
```

I need to convert/create a text file (`.txt`) with the character position. There are 2 scenarios should come in the text file ...1st scenario is...

1st column should have 5 positions but the column(ABC) has only 3 characters hence 2 character position should be blank and also the character should start at 50th position then the 2nd column should have 6 positions but the column(DEFG) has only 4 characters hence 2 columns should be blank and also the character should start at 60th position ...

Likewise nth column(NOPQ) value should come in 3rd line with the same condition(Character position should have 8 but only 4 characters occupied, rest character positions should be blank and also the character should start at 75th position)...At-last n+1 column(FJKAM) value has 6 characters but only 4 characters occupied,rest character positions should be blank but it has to come in 6th line and also the character should start at 150th position...

After the 1 scenario ends, second scenario should start with the same above conditions

And the text file should look like,(consider this as character position)

```
ABC  DEFG  HIJKLM        

                         NOPQ                FJKAM

MMESVS 
RSTUVWX    YZAB          
                         WGFWGW              OISNDDA  
KMAM
```

Thanks and appreciating your immediate response..

```
Sub Character postion()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
CellData = ""
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Charposition.txt"
Open FilePath For Output As #2
For i = 1 To LastRow
For j = 1 To LastCol
If j = LastCol Then
For i =1 to LastRow
For j = 0 To LastCol
CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
Else
CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
End If
Next j
Write #2, CellData
CellData = ""
Next i
Close #2
End Sub()
```

Comment: As it is very unlikely that someone will do all the work for you, please [edit] your question and add the code you already have tried. Explain what errors you got and where or where you got stuck. Also taking a [tour] and reading [ask] could help to improve your question.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: The code which I have used below...not able to place the position

Comment: You didn't ask a question yet nor did you explain what is wrong with your code. So please add this to your original question too. And a nice indentation of the code would improve the readability a lot.

Comment: To achieve what you want you need to calculate how many spaces you need to add between your data. So if your first column is at maximum `maxChr = 5` characters then for `ABC` you need to add `maxChr - Len("ABC") = 5 - 3 = 2` spaces. So it is all about adding the correct amount of spaces: So `String$(maxChr - Len("ABC")," ")` should output 2 spaces.

Comment: "Likewise nth column(NOPQ) value should come in 3rd line" really makes no sense. "Likewise" suggests that this is as before -- but nowhere before do you start writing things to another line. The jump from line 1 to line 3 is completely mysterious. It is also mysterious where the numbers 50 and 60 come from. Please explain.

Comment: Line 2 will be blank so I skip to line 3

Comment: But *why*? Why move to another line at all -- why not further on the first line? You haven't explained the logic of what you are doing.

Comment: As per my project requirement, they asked me to skip the 2nd line as blank and they want to place the NOPQ on 3rd line at 75th position

Comment: "As per my project requirement ... " that doesn't help us since we don't know what your project requirements are. As written, your question can't be answered.

Comment: Apologies for not clear.. let me try again in short..I need to create a notepad from an excel sheet..each cell value as its own character length but they asked me to allocate certain character length and also to start that character at some position..For example, Value "ABC" should start from "50th" position in the notepad and the character length should be "5". Since "ABC" has only 3 characters, 54th and 55th position should be empty...As the same, next cell value should start from "56th" position..so on..As the same, next line should be blank and again start 3rd line but on "75th" position

Comment: I wanna thank you everyone whoever try to understand my comments and queries. I am happy that you are taking part of my struggling in this part...Request to share your thoughts more

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any logical mapping or a formula for the length and each column length should be defined individually:

```
'.....
For j = 1 To LastCol
    Select Case j 
        Case 1
            n = 5 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
        Case 2
            n = 8 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
        '.....
     End Select

    CellData = CellData "|" &space(n)&Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
Next j
```

Here, `Space(n)` will add `n` spaces. The 'n' is counted as the the fixed length of column - length of existing text.

I use `"|"` as delimiter for cells. If you don't need it you can skip.

```
    CellData = CellData "|" &space(n)&Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
```

will add spaces before (to the left of) the cell value;

```
    CellData = CellData "|" &Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)&space(n)
```

will add spaces after (to the right of) the cell value;